# Quantitative metathesis in other languages than Ancient Greek?

Tags: sound-change, greek, metathesis

The Attic-Ionic dialects of Ancient Greek underwent a sound change whereby, in a sequence of a long vowel followed by a short vowel, the quantities were switched: -V:V- became -VV:-, e.g. *-e:o- > -eo:-*.

Has a metathesis of this kind occurred -- or does it occur as a synchronic process -- in any other language?

Comment: The only language I have ever heard of where it happened more than rarely is (Proto-)Greek. But it must be hard to spot or notice without someone pointing it out...great question!

Comment: @Cerberus Do you mean you know of sporadic cases of QM in other languages?

Comment: I intentionally left that bit vague, because the answer will disappoint: I seem to remember reading/hearing about it once or twice as happening in other languages, but I have no idea how or where, sorry.

Comment: You may argue that the -VR- > -RV:- metathesis in South Slavic languages is quantitative in nature. This said, though, I should point out that the Slavic languages had eventually lost its quantitative features and substituted them with qualitative ones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any language that has this sort of metathesis *in vowels* other than Hellenic, and since this has gone unanswered for over five years, I suspect there may not be one. But there are a few related phenomena which are worth mentioning.

*Compensatory lengthening* is a process that happens in several languages (including Ancient Greek): when a consonant is lost for any reason, the vowel before tends to be lengthened. For example, English "night" originally had a short `/i/`; when the `/x/` after it was lost, the vowel lengthened, giving `/i:/` (which became `/aj/` in the Great Vowel Shift).

More relevantly, *the Littera law* ("inverse compensatory lengthening") is a sound change that happened in Latin in the early centuries BC. It's named after the word *littera* "letters", from earlier *lītera*; in certain environments, the sequence `V:C` became `VC:`. This happened with sonorants as well as plosives, such as *flāma* > *flamma* "flames".

Comment: I'm not sure that "flamma" is an example of the "littera law". Although "littera"-type alternations seem to be fairly poorly understood, this [summmary by Michael Weiss](http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/weiss/Observations_on_the_littera_rule.pdf) says on page 7 that "flama" is probably just a "defective" spelling, which I understand to mean one where single M is used to write [mː]. The etymological explanations that I've read indicate that the word would be expected to have originally had a geminate; it's supposed to come from complete assimilation of the G in flăg- (as in flagro) to M.

Comment: @sumelic Fair! I was going from [this paper](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/phonology/Ranjan-abstract.pdf) but your evidence is convincing.